# How to add exception to not parse some types of files using jsoup in java ?

Tags: java, parsing, web-crawler, jsoup

I am writing a web crawler program using Jsoup library. (Sorry i can not post my code becase it too long to post it here).I need to crawl only URLs that can leed me to new links without crawling URLs with that starts with http or https and ending with image files, pdf, rar or zip files. I need just to crawl URLs that ending with .html, .htm, .jsp , .php and .asp etc.

> I have two question regarding this issue:

1- How can i prevent the program to not read other unneeded URLs (like: images, PDFs or RARs) ?

2- How can i improve this class to not waisting time to load whole URL content to memory then parse URLs from it ?

This is my code below :

```
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.security.*;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;


public class HTMLParser {

private static final int READ_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISSECS = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
private static HashMap <String, Integer> filecounter = new HashMap<> ();


public static List<LinkNodeLight> parse(LinkNode inputLink){
    List<LinkNodeLight> outputLinks = new LinkedList<>();
    try {
        inputLink.setIpAdress(IpFromUrl.getIp(inputLink.getUrl()));
        String url = inputLink.getUrl();
        if (inputLink.getIpAdress() != null) {
            url.replace(URLWeight.getHostName(url), inputLink.getIpAdress());
        }
        Document parsedResults =  Jsoup
                .connect(url)
                .timeout(READ_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISSECS)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")

                .get();
        inputLink.setSize(parsedResults.html().length());
        /* IP address moved here in order to speed up the process */
        inputLink.setStatus(LinkNodeStatus.OK);
        inputLink.setDomain(URLWeight.getDomainName(inputLink.getUrl()));
        if (true) {
            /* save the file to the html */
            String filename = parsedResults.title();//digestBig.toString(16) + ".html";
            if (filename.length() > 24) {
                filename = filename.substring(0, 24);
            }
            filename = filename.replaceAll("[^\\w\\d\\s]", "").trim();
            filename = filename.replaceAll("\\s+",  " ");

            if (!filecounter.containsKey(filename)) {
                filecounter.put(filename, 1);
            } else {
                Integer tmp = filecounter.remove(filename);
                filecounter.put(filename, tmp + 1);
            }
            filename = filename + "-" + (filecounter.get(filename)).toString() + ".html";
            filename = Paths.get("downloads", filename).toString();
            inputLink.setFileName(filename);
            /* use md5 of url as file name */
            try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename)))) {
                out.println("<!--" + inputLink.getUrl() + "-->");
                out.print(parsedResults.html());
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        String tag;
        Elements tagElements;
        List<LinkNode> result;


        tag = "a[href";
        tagElements = parsedResults.select(tag);
        result = toLinkNodeObject(inputLink, tagElements, tag);
        outputLinks.addAll(result);


        tag = "area[href";
        tagElements = parsedResults.select(tag);
        result = toLinkNodeObject(inputLink, tagElements, tag);
        outputLinks.addAll(result);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        inputLink.setParseException(e);
        inputLink.setStatus(LinkNodeStatus.ERROR);
    }

    return outputLinks;
}


static List<LinkNode> toLinkNodeObject(LinkNode parentLink, Elements tagElements, String tag) {
    List<LinkNode> links = new LinkedList<>();
    for (Element element : tagElements) {

        if(isFragmentRef(element)){
            continue;
        }

        String absoluteRef = String.format("abs:%s", tag.contains("[") ? tag.substring(tag.indexOf("[") + 1, tag.length()) : "href");
        String url = element.attr(absoluteRef);

        if(url!=null && url.trim().length()>0) {
            LinkNode link = new LinkNode(url);
            link.setTag(element.tagName());
            link.setParentLink(parentLink);
            links.add(link);
        }
    }
    return links;
}

static boolean isFragmentRef(Element element){
    String href = element.attr("href");
    return href!=null && (href.trim().startsWith("#") || href.startsWith("mailto:"));
}
}
```

Comment: Did you read http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax? Based on example `img[src~=(?i)\.(png|jpe?g)]` you could create selector like `a[href~=(?i)\.(htm|html|restOfWhatYouWantToPars)$]` to select only these links which you want to crawl.

Comment: Thank you i have tried it but what about my 2nd question can you tell me how to improve it ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do in 2nd question. How do you want to find links from text which is not downloaded? How `doc.select(cssQuery)` can work if `doc` is not loaded?

Comment: I don't know i was thinking to speed up parsing process because when i am taking crawled average per time, i saw there are different and not stable. Some time i am crawling 20 urls/S and sometimes 1 url/S. I was thinking it is because jsoup is loading contents of url to memory then start parsing it. As you know these days even if you have a small size page it will content tens lines of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add another solution to Pshemo for your first question. You may want to make a regex to compare to so that you don't even take the element and put it in the list
in method **"static List toLinkNodeObject"** maybe something like 
**"[http].+[^(pdf|rar|zip)]"** and match your url to the regex. This will speed up the program too because you won't even be adding those links to parse for.

```
    String url = element.attr(absoluteRef);

    if(url!=null && url.trim().length()>0 
                 && url.matches("[http].+[^(pdf|rar|zip)]")) {
        LinkNode link = new LinkNode(url);
        link.setTag(element.tagName());
        link.setParentLink(parentLink);
        links.add(link);
    }
```

As to speed up the class as a whole, it would help to multithread the downloading and parsing and allow the multiple threads to get and validate the information.